# Divisibility problem with product of two primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Be $n=pq$ a natural number product of two different primes $p,q$.

Prove, that on the set $\{1.2,2.3,...,n(n+1)\}$ there are exactly 4 numbers divisible by $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Chinese Remainder Theorem.

We want $ i (i+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. What does that tell you about $ i \pmod{p}$? How about $ i \pmod{q}$?

And hence, why are there 4 solutions?

Comment: Do you think such a sophisticated tool ois necessary? Just use the fact that $p$ and $q$ are prime should be enough, don't you think?

Comment: what it tells me is that $i$ or $i+1$ must be divisible by p, then the cases $ n (n+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ and $ (n-1)n  \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. the same for $q$. but how do I justify that this are the only ones?

Comment: @FranckN The first half of your statement is true. We must have $ i \equiv 0, -1 \pmod{p} $ and $ i \equiv 0, -1 \pmod{q}$. Why does this yield exactly 4 solutions to $i \pmod{n}$?

Comment: because i'll get four different combinations, and using the Chinese Remainder Theorem i'll get four answers.